# Boot-repair Boot Info: dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I cannot boot Ubuntu installed alongside with Windows 8.1 on my laptop with UEFI (Sony SVP1322R4RBI).

I followed the instructions on dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu, tried **Boot-Repair** with «recommended repair», then I manually set {bootmgr} option using Windows bcdedit, both

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

and

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

But there is no any effect, the laptop boots directly into Windows. 
Here is the **report of Boot-Repair** http://paste.ubuntu.com/9616775/

Maybe some advanced options would be helpful...

### UPDATE 01

Here is my UEFI BIOS screens: [link to dropbox (I cannot post images)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ko5w3aej0whgnj4/AADrFq4L8-vhUWvZcE7gklDLa?dl=0)

I've tried all F-keys, but I can't load boot menu.

### Solved

I've renamed `grubx64.efi` into `EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`, now everything is ok! As I understand, some models of Sony VAIO use only `bootx64.efi` bootloader.

Comment: If you're going directly to Windows, you should probably install `grub` again. You'll need to boot using a USB drive, or even selecting the partition in which Ubuntu is installed through the Boot Menu from your BIOS.

Comment: I have reinstalled grub via USB, no effect.

Comment: I've also checked with **bcdedit** that `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and `shimx64.efi` exist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the following link will definitely solve your issue. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd.

Comment: No, I cannot install grub on /dev/sda: `grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.`

Comment: You could better use the command "bootsect /nt60 SYS /force" in the command prompt after getting logged onto Windows. Then, follow the steps given in the above mentioned site.

Comment: Have you tried opening up the EFI/BIOS setup/configuration tool on your laptop at boot time. There should be a list of options at the splash screen that comes up at boot. It's often something like F2 or F12, but it varies from manufacturer to manufacturer. If GRUB2 is installed correctly in your EFI partition, you may just need to tell your EFI to boot from that boot manager instead of the Windows one.

Comment: I've tried all F-keys and not only F-keys at boot time, but there is no boot menu, I think :(

Comment: Please convert your `solved` section into an own answer and mark it as the right one . This is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed `grubx64.efi` into `EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`. Now everything is ok. As I understand it, some models of Sony VAIO use only the `bootx64.efi` boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used to dual-boot and I enabled the windows bootloader to start when pressing F12(you can change this in the BIOS of your PC). I then pressed F12(you PC probably has a different F command) and chose to boot Ubuntu.

Downsides to this method:

1. Windows will still boot automatically unless you press the F command when booting.
2. Start up time for either OS will be slowed Down by the whole process

Comment: I have only `UEFI/Legacy` and `Secure Boot Enabled/Disabled` options in BIOS, but there is no any possibility to choose system boot.

Comment: Try with your F-Commands and see if you get to a menu that looks like the image in the link below. If you do chose the Ubuntu partition option.

Comment: https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTllM2OtIrq3ukgYFUhLyF5vKKaLsb8aB__Upuol1ZkcmAVyfs7uw

Comment: ignore the yellow arrow

Comment: I've tried all F-commands, but I cannot enter any boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've been looking at your Pastebin from Boot Repair, and here's what it looks like to me:

You've got all your partitions listed there, and it's listed which ones contain bootloaders.

`/dev/sda1` seems to contain your Windows bootloaders and a secureboot handler `/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` for Ubuntu. I believe there should also be a grubx64.efi in the same directory as shimx64.efi, though, or it won't hand-off correctly.

`/dev/sda3` looks like it contains Windows bootloaders and properly configured secure boot bootloaders for Ubuntu.

`/dev/sda7` looks like it contains a traditional GRUB2 bootloader (and your Ubuntu installation). If you reboot and open up your EFI configuration tool at startup (just press whatever key the splash screen lists for "setup" or "configuration utility" before that boot splash screen disappears) and tell EFI to boot from one of the two partitions that have GRUB2 installed on it. I would choose the one installed on `/dev/sda7`, personally.

If Secure Boot isn't already disabled, I'd disable it. You say in another comment that you have found the option for that.

You may also need to change some settings to tell it to boot from that partition by default, depending on how your EFI setup utility behaves.  If you set it to boot from GRUB2 by default, you should be able to use GRUB2 to choose which OS to boot from in future rather than having to use EFI. (The `grub.cfg` file reproduced in your pastebin looks like it does contain the entries for booting Windows by handing off to the Windows bootloader.)

If your EFI doesn't provide you with options of which device to boot in the setup (which it typically *does* do, so I'd be kind of shocked if it didn't give you an option *anywhere* to configure which device to boot from), there may just be a different key you need to press on the boot splash screen to get the boot device/partition options to appear.

If you can't find these options, perhaps you could provide some images of your boot screen and EFI setup utilities so we could look at them and see if we can spot the setting you need?

There is another option that may be worth pursing if we can't get this to work: properly installing GRUB2 to /dev/sda1 where the Windows bootloader lives. I would consider [using partimage or dd to make an image of the partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging), first, though. Then, if something went horribly wrong, you'd be able to restore the partition to its original state.

Comment: I load BIOS with «Assist» button and I cannot enter any boot menu at the boot time... Here is the BIOS screens https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ko5w3aej0whgnj4/AADrFq4L8-vhUWvZcE7gklDLa?dl=0