# Grub is bypassed by Windows booter

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Latest Windows update messed up with grub. I fixed it using boot-repair, but Windows was damaged as a result. So I decided to reinstall Window 10 by deleting all partitions and then installing from usb. The I booted from Ubuntu 14.04LTS usb to install Ubuntu it went through all the way to the end successfully. The problem is when I restart my computer, grub is totally bypassed by Windows booter. I have used boot-repair getting the "successfully installed" message restarted, and the same happened. I even logged into Windows command line as an Administrator and typed `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` also with a successful message, and I still get straight to Windows 10.

What else can I do?

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/565920/37165) attempted similar command and failed. The solution from OP suggested to rename the `*.efi` file accordingly, however said to work only for some Sony VAIO models. Something you can try while waiting for other answer.

Comment: @clerikimura that did not work either

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from an Ubuntu live disk. This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com] and post the URL to the document here. Without the information in that file, any answer will be based on guesswork and assumptions.

Comment: Thanks Rod I could not try that. I gave up on dual booting in favor of Ubuntu-only. This computer is the tool I use for work and it took me more than a day without luck. However I will try some other day.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Windows 10 system and disable hibernation.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the old version of Windows Control Panel.
Go to the Power Settings ... disable Fast startup.

Shutdown the PC completely - do NOT reboot !
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default OS.

In case GRUB does not appear, reinstall it.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
On desktop open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use GParted.
It is included in the Ubuntu installation media.
This assumes system installation in EFI mode.

Comment: how do you disable the fast startup?

Comment: What system partition?

Comment: I have done all steps as Told here, still is bypassing grub!

Comment: @awavi : Uncheck fast startup in power settings (first enable hidden settings) to disable it - the system partition is the ext4 partition where Ubuntu is installed - please repeat everything again ... good luck ! :)

Comment: I did everything again but I gave up on Windows. My best guess is that it was rewritting the bios boot order. I am sorry I gave up but it took me more than one day and I need to work on this computer